# Best way to display a java object that contains csv data in a JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, csv, servlets

I have a jsp that gathers data from the user and passes that data to a servlet. The servlet uses that data to query an api and the response is a string object that contains csv data, which is forwarded to a search results jsp page.

In the search results jsp page I call the object. It's just a string of csv values and it looks bad on the page. I'm a total novice when it comes to web app development. Any idea the best way to parse the csv data in such a way that it looks better? Maybe into a HTML table? All I can find is info on parsing through a csv file, not an object with csv data in it.

I'm sure there's a simple way to handle this but after a whole day of combing the internet I need a little help where to look...

-----Edited to add sample data.

The data is returned to the jsp like so.

product_nbr,member_nbr,prod_cd,create_dt XYZ0000,000,777,2015-10-30

The first 4 fields are the headers and the data follows in line. I would like it to look like this..

(stackoverflow doesn't allow the table tag, but you really I just want to be able to display an HTML table on screen)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>product_nbr</td>
<td>member_nbr</td>
<td>prod_cd</td>
<td>create_dt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>XYZ0000</td>
<td>000</td> 
<td>777</td>
<td>777</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: give as some sample data and how you want the data to look like

Comment: I edited my original question

Comment: I ended up writing another stringbuilder class that parsed the CSV and built the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this article:

http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-with-examples-jstl-core-tags

It shows you how to use JSTL in a JSP. You have to use the forEach tag like this, but before yoy have to parse your csv file into a array.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

```
String a = "product_nbr,member_nbr,prod_cd,create_dt XYZ0000,000,777,2015-10-30";
String[] b = a.split(",");
```

Este es un JSP de ejemplo

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
<tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```